# My element overflows its div onto another when resizing screen. Why is this happening?

Tags: html, css, overflow, element

When the site is in full screen, the layout is fine but when I resize the window to a smaller size, elements overflow onto other elements.

I tried wrapping the elements inside a main div but it still overflows

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:25vh; display: block">
  <!-- <h1 id="projects">Projects</h1> -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-header bg-transparent">Project Name: </div>
      <a href=""> <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505238680356-667803448bb6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="card-img-top" alt="..."></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Description: </p>
        <p class="card-text">Languages/Frameworks utilized: </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

It should stay inside one div and not overflow out of it.

Comment: Post your css code

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please can you calrify which elements are overflowing onto other elements - when I paste the code given into bootply, everything seems fine right down to mobile resolution (which cannot be seen in bootply).  Also please take the time to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are overriding card width here:

class="card col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12" **style="width: 18rem;"**

So your cards are not responsive anymore.